# Setuptools, skbuild and Pybind11 : wrong library location

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, cpython, pybind11

I made a python interface to a fairly large C++ project, using Pybind11 : https://pypi.org/project/cytosim/
I wrote a setup.py file that does compile the library (provided some libraries are installed) ; compilation relies on skbuild

However, the compiled library ends up in the wrong place !
eg it ends up in /home/XXXX/anaconda3/lib

Where I thought it should be (/home/XXXX/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages), there is just cytosim-0.0.2.dist-info

How do I make sure that "pip3 install cytosim" creates a folder "cytosim" in /home/XXXX/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages and puts the library there ?